# How do I upload source code to Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I am trying to upload a some web files that are in a folder to my Wordpress site, the three files are a HTML, JS, and CSS. I only really need the HTML and JS files but I can't seem to find out how. I do realize there you can create a HTML file on Wordpress then simply copy your code over but it doesn't really solve the JS problem. Any help would be appreciated thanks. (First time Wordpress user)

Comment: Its not clear what are you trying to do with those files ?

Comment: Just simply making a new page for a user to input some info, the JS simply just sends it to a firebase DB

Comment: WordPress works very differently than other CMS's. You cannot just add HTML, CSS and JS inside a folder and expect it to run. Read this : https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins